# Image Magick usage

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am getting this error when i am trying to process an image file using Image Magick functions.

```
Image Magick Error

Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in F:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\image_magic\create_image.php on line 2

Program

<?php
$im = new Imagick();
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "magick:rose");
$im->setImageFormat("png");
$im->roundCorners(5,3);
$type=$im->getFormat();
header("Content-type: $type");
//$im->adaptiveBlurImage(5,3); // Adaptively blur an image //
$im->adaptiveResizeImage(1024,768); // Adaptively resize image //
echo $im->getimageblob();
?>
```

Comment: That means the Imagick extension is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned already in the comments, this is almost certainly because ImageMagick is not installed. It's a PECL extension so is not installed by default. The [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) cover this along with the installation steps.